# Formik handleSubmit is not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to validate a form before submitting using formik and yup validation. The form consist of two parts, the first form is validated then loads next one. And am setting a state `handleShow(true)` to trigger the second form. Below is my code

```
  const UserOnboardSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    gender: Yup.string().required('please select the gender'),
    firstName: Yup.string().required('Please enter your first name'),
    lastName: Yup.string().required('Please enter your last name'),
    mobile: Yup.string()
      .required('Please enter your mobile number')
      .matches(phoneRegExp, 'Please enter valid phone number'),
    workExperience: Yup.string().required('Please enter your work experience'),
  });



  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      gender: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      mobile: '',
      workExperience: '',
      currentRole: '',
    },
    validationSchema: UserOnboardSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
      formik.resetForm();
    },
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    formik.handleSubmit();

    if (Object.entries(formik.errors).length === 0) {
      handleShow(true);
    } else {
      handleShow(false);
    }
  };
```

Here is the problem in the `handleSubmit` the `formik.handleSubmit` is not working. It's directly accessing the if/else condition thus loading second form without validating the first one.

```
    if (Object.entries(formik.errors).length === 0) {
      handleShow(true);
    } else {
      handleShow(false);
    }
```

but if I give`handleShow(true)` direclty to formik, like this

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      gender: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      mobile: '',
      workExperience: '',
      currentRole: '',
    },
    validationSchema: UserOnboardSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);

      handleShow(true); #----> Giving here.

      formik.resetForm();
    },
  });
```

then the formik and Yup validation works. Im unable to figure out whats causing this issue?

Comment: You can use also the `touched` property to see if any element has been focused on. So check if formik.touched has at least one key, and formik.error have no key

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see what's wrong without the form itself. Here are some helpful troubleshooting tips though...

Formik won't trigger the `onSubmit` method, if there are errors in the form. So, my go-to would be to:

1. Check for any errors in the form,
2. Look at the `initialValues` object for any unused fields

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error before.
looks like it's coming from Validation. I removed shape() and moved validate into object(). hope it can help you